# How To Set Wine Executable Location In KDE?

Tags: linux, kde, freebsd, wine, dolphin-file-manager

I'm using FreeBSD so that might have resulted in an abnormal installation location for Wine, but it's in `/usr/local/bin/wine64`.  For whatever reason KDE is not picking up the location for Wine and believes it to not exist.

Is there a way to change the path KDE is looking in to try to execute Wine from the context menu item `Open with Wine Windows Program Loader` in `Dolphin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases you should use `wine-i386` package, whatever arch you are running on. But if you want to use wine64 and fix that context menu action, take a look at `/usr/local/share/applications/wine.desktop` file.